# Why 'multi-part identifier' and why can't it be bound?

Tags: t-sql

I continually receive these errors when I try to do a select with linked server on other tables. I end up rewriting the query, changing the order of joins, modifying some groups and then it works at the end, but I can not understand it.

```
SELECT     TOP (100) PERCENT [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_COGNOME + ' ' + [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_NOME AS UTENTE, [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.TELEFONI.S_TEL AS TEL, 
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.SEDI.S_DESCR AS PIANO, [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_QT AS NETNAME, [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.EMAIL.S_EMAIL AS EMAIL, 
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_DOMINIO AS DOMINIO, [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.UFFICI.S_DESCR AS SERVIZIO, [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.AZIENDE.S_DESCR AS AZIENDA
FROM         [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.AZIENDE RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.EMAIL RIGHT OUTER JOIN
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA ON [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.EMAIL.ID_UTENTE = [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.INCID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.SEDI ON [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.ID_SEDE = [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.SEDI.INCID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.TELEFONI ON [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.INCID = [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.TELEFONI.ID_UTENTE LEFT OUTER JOIN
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.UFFICI ON [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.ID_UFFICIO = [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.UFFICI.INCID ON 
                      [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.AZIENDE.INCID = [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.ID_AZIENDA
ORDER BY [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_COGNOME, [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_NOME

GO
```

> Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.EMAIL.ID_UTENTE" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 18 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.INCID" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.ID_SEDE" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 19 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.SEDI.INCID" could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.INCID" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 20 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.TELEFONI.ID_UTENTE" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.ID_UFFICIO" could not
>   be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 21 The multi-part
>   identifier "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.UFFICI.INCID" could
>   not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22 The multi-part
>   identifier "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.AZIENDE.INCID" could
>   not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 22 The multi-part
>   identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.ID_AZIENDA" could not
>   be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The multi-part
>   identifier "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_COGNOME"
>   could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The
>   multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_NOME" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 13 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.TELEFONI.S_TEL" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.SEDI.S_DESCR" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_QT" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 14 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.EMAIL.S_EMAIL" could not be
>   bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 The multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_DOMINIO" could not
>   be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 The multi-part
>   identifier "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.UFFICI.S_DESCR" could
>   not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 15 The multi-part
>   identifier "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.AZIENDE.S_DESCR"
>   could not be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 23 The
>   multi-part identifier
>   "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_COGNOME" could not
>   be bound.
>   Msg 4104, Level 16, State 1, Line 23 The multi-part
>   identifier "ZILNNM10.IT.SUB.FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0.dbo.ANAGRAFICA.S_NOME"
>   could not be bound.

Comment: Try using Aliases and can you edit your question using Formatting so it's easier to read

Comment: Side note: The fact that you are using `SELECT TOP (100) PERCENT` with `ORDER BY` leads me to think this is intended to be a view, a derived table, or a common table expression (cte). If this is the case, you should remove the `TOP (100) PERCENT` and the `ORDER BY` clause, since views, ctes and tables are unsorted by nature.
This means that even if you have a view like this `SELECT TOP(100) PERCENT <columns list> FROM <table> ORDER BY <columns list>`, You still need to specify the `ORDER BY` clause when you are selecting from it to ensure the order of the rows in the result set.

Answer (score 0):

Disclaimer: This is not a solution to your problem, but it's a major step on getting there.

The error you get means that SQL Server can't find the identifiers you specified in your query. Since every identifier in your original query is a multi part identifier, it's hard to read and harder to debug, so I've aliased all your tables to simplify the query you posted.

Also, mixing left joins with right joins is a recipe for disaster, so I did my best to fix that. This query should not get rid of all the error messages you've got but it should minimize them and help you find the problems.

Also, I've removed the `TOP 100 PERCENT` and `ORDER BY` clause. See my comment for details.

So here is the simplified query, I hope it helps.

```
SELECT ANAGRAFICA.S_COGNOME + ' ' + 
       ANAGRAFICA.S_NOME AS UTENTE, 
       TELEFONI.S_TEL AS TEL, 
       SEDI.S_DESCR AS PIANO, 
       ANAGRAFICA.S_QT AS NETNAME, 
       EMAIL.S_EMAIL AS EMAIL, 
       ANAGRAFICA.S_DOMINIO AS DOMINIO, 
       UFFICI.S_DESCR AS SERVIZIO, 
       AZIENDE.S_DESCR AS AZIENDA
FROM [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.AZIENDE As AZIENDE
RIGHT JOIN 
(
    [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.ANAGRAFICA As ANAGRAFICA 
    LEFT JOIN [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.EMAIL As EMAIL ON EMAIL.ID_UTENTE = ANAGRAFICA.INCID 
    LEFT JOIN [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.SEDI As SEDI ON ANAGRAFICA.ID_SEDE = SEDI.INCID 
    LEFT JOIN [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.TELEFONI As TELEFONI ON ANAGRAFICA.INCID = TELEFONI.ID_UTENTE 
    LEFT JOIN [ZILNNM10.IT.SUB].[FZ221-IT-DBA_3.0].dbo.UFFICI As UFFICI ON ANAGRAFICA.ID_UFFICIO = UFFICI.INCID 
 ) ON AZIENDE.INCID = ANAGRAFICA.ID_AZIENDA
```